# How to create partition in a functional index in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, sqlperformance

im trying to create a partition on a functional index in oracle , but it is failing with the below error .

Error :

> ORA-30555: global index partitioning key is an expression

Syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX TMP_ARA_I9 ON TMP_ARA (
UPPER(JOB_TITLE) ASC,
   UPPER(COMPANY_NAME) ASC
   )
global PARTITION BY HASH ( UPPER(JOB_TITLE) ,
   UPPER(COMPANY_NAME) 
   ) PARTITIONS 4;
```

Comment: You cannot use expressions. In your specific case, you would have to store the job title and company name in their uppercase form and then create the index on those two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Create virtual columns at your table:

```
ALTER TABLE TMP_ARA ADD (
   UPPER_JOB_TITLE VARCHAR2(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER(JOB_TITLE)) VIRTUAL,
   UPPER_COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR2(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER(COMPANY_NAME)) VIRTUAL
);
```

Then you can create an index on there:

```
CREATE INDEX TMP_ARA_I9 ON TMP_ARA (
   UPPER_JOB_TITLE, UPPER_COMPANY_NAME
)
GLOBAL PARTITION BY HASH ( 
   UPPER_JOB_TITLE, UPPER_COMPANY_NAME
) PARTITIONS 4;
```